# How to plot time data with limited range x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot

```
d=read.table(text="in_type, in_time, out_type, out_time, d2d, e2e
    R1,14:56:04.434285,R2,14:56:04.434534,152,249
    R1,14:56:04.522163,R2,14:56:04.522325,113,162
    R1,14:56:04.606073,R2,14:56:04.606228,112,155
    R1,14:56:04.824225,R2,14:56:04.824391,116,166
    R1,14:56:06.621347,R2,14:56:06.621511,116,164
    R1,14:56:37.677250,R2,14:56:37.677452,135,202
    R1,14:56:38.897656,R2,14:56:38.897839,123,183
    R1,14:56:50.361073,R2,14:56:50.361268,127,195
    R1,14:59:09.768824,R3,14:59:09.769006,138,182
", sep=',', header=T)
d=d[order(d$in_time),]
d$in_s = strptime(substr(d$in_time,1,8),"%H:%M:%S")
plot(d$in_s,d$d2d)

plot(d$in_s,d$d2d, xlim=c('14:56:06','14:56:37'))
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value

class(d$in_s) # will get POSIXlt
plot(d$in_s,d$d2d, xlim=as.POSIXlt(c('14:56:06','14:56:37', format="%H:%M:%S"))
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
```

Comment: Your `xlim` values are text - `c('14:56:06','14:56:37')`. They have to be a numeric range instead. Your `d` also doesn't have a header properly assigned. Please check your examples before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ggplot2 e.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(d) + geom_line(aes(x = in_s,y = d2d)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(limits = as.POSIXct(c("14:56:06", "14:56:37"), format = "%H:%M:%S"), breaks=date_breaks("1 secs"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I using the following code, but I wish x-label be %H:%M:%S format, `ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=in_s,y=d2d)) + xlim(as.POSIXct(c('14:56:06','14:56:37'), format="%H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: could not found function 'date_breaks'

Comment: Use library(scales). Edited above

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a

> header=T

to read your data. For the

> xlim

It can't take string directly. You need to format it. The following codes should work for you

```
 d=read.table(text="in_type, in_time, out_type, out_time, d2d, e2e
                 R1,14:56:04.434285,R2,14:56:04.434534,152,249
                 R1,14:56:04.522163,R2,14:56:04.522325,113,162
                 R1,14:56:04.606073,R2,14:56:04.606228,112,155
                 R1,14:56:04.824225,R2,14:56:04.824391,116,166
                 R1,14:56:06.621347,R2,14:56:06.621511,116,164
                 R1,14:56:37.677250,R2,14:56:37.677452,135,202
                 R1,14:56:38.897656,R2,14:56:38.897839,123,183
                 R1,14:56:50.361073,R2,14:56:50.361268,127,195
                 R1,14:59:09.768824,R3,14:59:09.769006,138,182", sep=',',header=T)
    d=d[order(d$in_time),]
    d$in_s = strptime(substr(d$in_time,1,8),"%H:%M:%S")

    plot(d$in_s,d$d2d, xlim=as.POSIXct(c("14:56:06", "14:56:37"), format = "%H:%M:%S") )
```

Comment: x-axis labels seem to be missing.

Comment: I'm wonder why the class(d$in_s) is POSIXlt, why can not just use as.POSIXlt?

Comment: If you look at ?xlim: "numeric vectors of length 2, giving the x and y coordinates ranges". You could use axis.POSIXct for the HH:MM:SS but you might need to subset your dataframe first.